# No File Menu in blender 2.78a

Tags: interface

I have Blender 2.78 and I'm trying to save my project however I don't see the file tab or add tab in the top menu bar. I see create to add mesh so that's solved but no file tab.

Comment: well you can save with ctrl-s or ctrl-w in the meanwhile. You should have hidden the top "info" editor, where the File menu is usually.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the current editor

[image]

What ever you have it will drop down a big menu and select
(i) icon i.e info

[image]

And you will find your file menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While changing the type of window at the top is one possibility, another is that you may have collapsed the menus, which will leave three lines in place of the menus.

[image: info with collapsed menus]

To replace the menus right click on the three lines and choose *Collapse Menus*

[image: un-collapse menus]